# Is it possible to put a UITableViewController inside a CollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

Right now I have a CollectionViewCell that contains a UITableView. Is it possible to put a full UITableViewController in there?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you write any code about?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, as you can use a ContainerView to embed a UITableViewController. However, for most cases I would imagine that simply putting a UITableView inside the CollectionViewCell is preferred.

Comment: Because there are mean spirited people out there that just do it out of spite. No comment or rationale given.